# failed to deploy kubernetes controller on google container engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

my yaml file:

```
kind: ReplicationController
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: locust-master
  labels:
    name: locust
    role: master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: locust
    role: master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: locust
        role: master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: locust
          image: gcr.io/MY_PROJECT/locust-tasks:latest
          env:
            - name: LOCUST_MODE
              key: LOCUST_MODE
              value: master
            - name: TARGET_HOST
              key: TARGET_HOST
              value: http://MY_WEBSITE.io
          ports:
            - name: loc-master-web
              containerPort: 8089
              protocol: TCP
            - name: loc-master-p1
              containerPort: 5557
              protocol: TCP
            - name: loc-master-p2
              containerPort: 5558
              protocol: TCP
```

running `kubectl create -f locust-master-controller.yaml`
gives:

error: error validating "locust-master-controller.yaml": error validating data: [found invalid field key for v1.EnvVar, found invalid field key for v1.EnvVar]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I am basically following the instructions word for word on:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/distributed-load-testing-using-kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete these two lines:

`key: LOCUST_MODE`

and

`key: TARGET_HOST`
.

There is no key called `key` in the `env` section.  Complete [documentation for env is here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#envvar-v1-core).

Comment: You are right, there is an error in the docs in [the link you gave](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/distributed-load-testing-using-kubernetes).

Comment: Sent PR to fix those docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/distributed-load-testing-using-kubernetes/pull/18